# Checking the input file

Tags: c++, input

I want to check the following input **text file:**

```
#HEADLINE   
#some line of text (comment)

#size of logo 
SIZE: 11  6
VALUE: 200

LOGO:
IIGGGGGGGII
IIG------II
IIGGGGGGGII
IIG------II
IIGGGGGGGII
```

- File must **start** with the word #HEADLINE, and **last** entry must be LOGO ( and then the actual picture of logo) : .
- Order of remaining lines does not matter, but there may be only **one entry 
  per line** .
- Empty lines should be ignored.
- Lines starting with hash symbol **#** are comments and should be ignored
- **SIZE** , **VALUE** and **LOGO** entries may occur **only once**´, they must be in upper case.
- There may be **any number of spaces** between name (SIZE, VALUE, LOGO) and value 
   example: `SIZE    11   6`

  - Also, value must be integer greater than zero

My initial idea is to start wih:

```
std::ifstream infile("Myfile.txt")
if(!infile.is_open())
  return ERROR;

std::string str;
while(std::getline(infile, str)
{
  // check input
}
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Use regular expressions: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Comment: @Asesh thanks, this seems helpful, <regex> is part of c++ standard library if im not wrong? im only allowed to use those from standard library

Comment: yes, it is. More specifically it was added in C++11